# How can I Get birthday from OAuth facebook nodejs? (I can log it in the terminal but can't access it)

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I do console.log(profile) I get everything and when I do console.log(profile.name) I get my name but when I do console.log(profile.birthday) I get nothing...

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email', 'user_birthday'] }));
```

I get the following output in my terminal:

```
  _json: {
    id: '10216001524809335',
    name: 'Rani Verelst',
    last_name: 'Verelst',
    first_name: 'Rani',
    birthday: '05/26/1996',
    picture: { data: [Object] },
    email: 'verelst.rani@gmail.com'
  }
}
```

How can I use the birthday data to store and to use in my routers?

Comment: You will need to store the data in your db if you later want to retrieve it and serve it in your express server lets. You can use mongo, or MySQL, or pretty much any db depending on your architecture. It will help to provide more clarity and some sample code of what you are trying to achieve so that we can better answer your question

Comment: How can I store this data? because when i try to (for example: profile.birthday) than I dont get any result

Comment: @EdwardRomero When I do console.log(newUser.birthday) I get no anwer. Is this normal? Or my fault?

Answer (score 0):

The returned profile data can be accessed through ._json in the object so do the following to get all attributes by destructuring, including birthday as you mentioned

```
     const { first_name, last_name, birthday } = profile._json;
```

You can add the rest of the attributes to the destructure. If you don't want to destructure then just access directly

```
     const birthday = profile._json.birthday;
```